# GUI for LLDB (preferably most resembling xcode)

Tags: linux, c++, gui, c, debugging

I'm migrating from OSX to linux and one of the things I got used to developing c++ command line applications in Xcode is its superior debugger.
As LLDB is available under linux I wonder which GUI for it is most mature.

I'm looking for it to:

- be stable
- have a list of all active variables with current values
- easily access all project files within it and be able to set/clear breakpoints

Would be amazing if it could:

- show variables values after highlighting them in code (I don't think it's possible without whole IDE though)
- Show STL objects (maps, vectors) in a easy to read form (and copy to clipboard for visualisation in octave or matlab) (in Xcode it is necessary to unfold every key-value pair)

Thanks,
Mix

Comment: "Most functional and user friendly" would be a matter of opinion.  Could you please give some specific requirements.

Comment: Can't lldb work with gdb-oriented GUIs which allow replacing the debugger command?

Comment: Good point @einpoklum. It can with some, but not all. However I don't know which ones are recommended for gdb so the question remains.

Comment: @Chenmunka It's quite obvious as he referenced what he's used to, and anyone that has used a decent GUI knows and if you haven't then you cant help anyway. Some simple common sense needs to be applied : data, locals views, assembler and source panes, ability to navigate code as you debug,stack , hexdump , watchpoint list etc. All on the screen "at a glance". To name but some things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try one of the [GDB-frontend debuggers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends), and just tell it to use lldb in the backend.

Personally, I use [Eclipse CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/) as an IDE, which has an inbuilt debugger frontend of course, and sometimes [kdbg](http://www.kdbg.org/) - but it's not because they're better than others, it's just a personal preference.

Consider also [this review](https://web.archive.org/web/20140829070701/http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/13-linux-debuggers-for-c-reviewed/240156817) of several of the GDB frontends.

Comment: small correction: You probably meant to say "use lldb" in the backend.

Comment: @RichieHH: Thanks; but remember you can just make the edit yourself; this is a collaborative Q&A site - edits are meant for just this.